# Android: advanced compare of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, comparator

I have `ArrayList <Integer> a` which contains 100 random items [0:100) Items can be repeated.

Also, I have `int b = 50`. I want to sort the items in my **ArrayList** in **ascending** order of results of this expression:

```
Math.abs (ArrayList.get(index) - b);
```

For example:

`65 84 33 18 77...` - ArrayList **before**

`15 34 17 32 27` - Math.abs (ArrayList.get(index) - b) **before**;

`65 33 77 18 84...` - ArrayList **after**

`15 17 27 32 34` - Math.abs (ArrayList.get(index) - b) **after** (in ascending order);

I think, i can do this using **java.util.Comparator**, but I still don't understand, how it works. Can someone explait this? Or, maybe  there is another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you can use a comparator.

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    private final int b;

    public MyComparator(int b) { this.b = b; }

    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        Integer i1 = Math.abs(o1 - b);
        Integer i2 = Math.abs(o2 - b);
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

Then plug it into the Collections call:

```
Collections.sort(a,new MyComparator(50));
```

This will sort the `Integer` list according to the criteria in the comparator.

Comment: Make the b  as final to avoid unnecessary side effects

Comment: That's what I wanted you to infer. Now remove `static` modifier from `b`, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Yes, and it should be.

Comment: You confused me with that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Provide a custom `Comparator` for [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
final int b = ...;
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void compareTo(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
             Integer realI1 = (int)Math.abs(i1 - b);
             Integer realI2 = (int)Math.abs(i2 - b);
             return realI1.compareTo(realI2);
        }
    });
```